# Swapping Pointer Array (Pointer to Class) Elements

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

I created an pointer array that represents objects of Class called Sinif. `Sinfi *sinif = new Sinif[5]` As we know every element has an adres. In my home assignment ,For example I want to swap first element of sinif with second element with its adres. In Degistir Function It changes but only last written is running well. Let's say we want to change Sinif 0 with 1 it changes 0 to 1 but 1 stays as it was. Here is the photos for detailed example.

[image: Before Swapping]
[image: After Swapping]

in here, First User enters Which element to move than where to move and the program Looks for it in every Sinif Array when it finds it The adreses are collected to temp and temp2 after that It assign it.

```
Sinif *temp; 
Sinif *temp2;

   void Yonetim::SinifDegistir() {
    char DegisecekSinif;
    char YeniYeri;
    cout << "Degisecek Sinif Adi: "; cin >> DegisecekSinif;
    cout << "Yeni Sinif Yerinin Adi: "; cin >> YeniYeri;
    for (int i = 0; i < okul->SayacGet(); i++)
    {
        if (DegisecekSinif == okul->sinif[i].sinif) {
            temp = okul->sinif + i;
            for (int j = 0; j < okul->SayacGet(); j++)
            {
                if (YeniYeri == okul->sinif[j].sinif) {
                    temp2 = okul->sinif + j;
                    Degis(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
void Yonetim::Degis(int i, int j) {

    (okul->sinif[i]) = *temp2;
    (okul->sinif[j]) = *temp;
    TabloYazdirma();
}
```

Comment: What are `temp` and `temp2`? Which function here is supposed to do the swaps (I assume `Degis`, but it doesn't look like a proper swap)?

Comment: If you want to swap two elements of an array, you don't swap the addresses of the elements, you swap the elements themselves. And you do it with the [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) function.

Comment: `Sinfi *sinif = new Sinif[5]` is not an array of pointers.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Oh but It holds the objects in heap right? I just wanted to creade pointer to class in heap with using arrays

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes It worked Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `swap();` function which was recommended in comments instead of trying to get every element's adres also I added bool variable called degisti in order to prohibit from turning back to as it was

---

```
void Yonetim::SinifDegistir() {
    char DegisecekSinif;
    char YeniYeri;
    bool degisti = false;
    cout << "Degisecek Sinif Adi: "; cin >> DegisecekSinif;
    cout << "Yeni Sinif Yerinin Adi: "; cin >> YeniYeri;
    for (int i = 0; i < okul->SayacGet(); i++)
    {
        if (DegisecekSinif == okul->sinif[i].sinif && !degisti) {
            temp = okul->sinif + i;
            for (int j = 0; j < okul->SayacGet(); j++)
            {
                if (YeniYeri == okul->sinif[j].sinif) {
                    temp2 = okul->sinif + j;
                    Degis(i, j,degisti);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
void Yonetim::Degis(int i, int j, bool &degisti) {
    swap(okul->sinif[i], okul->sinif[j]); //changes 
    TabloYazdirma();
    degisti = true; //bool says it was swapped
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Sinfi *sinif = new Sinif[5]` creates an array of 5 Sinif instances in memory. Not pointers but the actual instances.

So when you later say:

```
(okul->sinif[i]) = *temp2;
```

What you do is copy the contents of the sinif from one to the other. Now both are the same. So the next line

```
(okul->sinif[j]) = *temp;
```

does nothing. `*temp` has already been overwritten with `*temp2` and you are simply copying it back.